# Flameshot on Gnome 42

Tags: security, fedora, gnome, wayland

A new security feature in somewhere in the display server/window manager stack prevents me from seamlessly using the much loved screen capture utility, Flameshot. I've google for how to restore the seamless experience. I'm not a OS hacker or software security architect, and most of the discussion is over my head.

Common sense tells me there must be a whitelist, or something that will let me use Flameshot without a security prompt "Share" popping up. I am looking for a setting that either disables this security feature, or adds Flameshot to list of trusted executables. Can someone please point me to that?

Comment: I've seen discussions about persistent share tokens, but I'm not sure if it's implemented yet in the current Fedora GNOME version.

Comment: @user1686 thanks for the update

Comment: If your first instinct is just to link to a meme of Linus yelling without any care about the nuances of what he's yelling about, yeah, that's not it.

Comment: Link wasn't for you.

Comment: In fact, I'll just delete the link. It serves no productive purpose. It was a flame shot. (Sorry for the bad pun.)